# Can't push to github origin master anymore

Tags: git, authentication, github

I am not able to push to origin anymore in Github. Yesterday I made a mistake when introducing my username and now every time I try `git push -u origin master` I immediately get the following message:

remote: Invalid username or password.
  fatal: Authentication failed for https://github.com/my_user_name/my_repo.git/

I do not even get the prompt for username or password anymore. 
I have tried creating a new OAuth token and also a new ssh key but nothing seems to be working.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Edits:
The .git/config file for the repo to push says:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://github.com/eduardopoleo/tesing1.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[credential]
    helper = cache [options]
```

Comment: what does it say in your .git/config for the "origin" remote?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got in contact with the guys from Github and the were able to help me solve the issue. Here I paste their mail:

> If you're using the SSH remote you shouldn't be asked for a username
>   or password. You can ensure you're set up to use SSH in a local
>   repository with a command like this:
>
> git remote set-url origin git@github.com:eduardopoleo/test1.git
>
> You could also try exiting the credential cache, which should cause it
>   to forget your username:
>
> git credential-cache exit

The first suggestion was the one that worked for me.

Comment: Switching from HTTPS to SSH solved the problem for me as well.

Answer (score 0):

Are you on Windows or Mac?  On Windows, the credentials are stored in Control Panel -> User Accounts -> choose your account (you're probably there) -> Manage your credentials -> choose "Windows Vault" (maybe already chosen), look though the list for github.com.  On Mac, it's generally stored in the Apple keychain.  Either edit your credentials so they're correct or delete them and then git will prompt again next time you connect.

Comment: The magic line is [credential]\nhelper = this-is-the-command.  I'm not familiar with `cache` as a credential store.  Perhaps delete this line and let git try using netrc.